# A different boot loop after flashing BLU phone

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop, blu-phones

This is the same BLU Life One X as in [Cannot get into recovery mode from boot-loop on BLU phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/174371/48717):

I followed the instructions and flashed the phone with [`BLU_L0070UU_V12_GENERIC`](https://mega.nz/#!Op1V2DIC!DZ1ziHRq50W3XJGJB44pQMDQqYofaXpIKicCVDS2lhw).

I am still in a boot loop, but less predictable:

- It shows 0%
- BLU/Bold Like Us
- Android is starting/optimizing app AAA of BBB
- Android is starting/starting apps
- Select language
- Checking connection
- (Sometimes) updating software
- (Sometimes) starting the cellular service
- Enter email/password of the account to which the android was synced

At any point in the above, the phone may go dark and restart.
I never managed to finish typing the Google account password.
At some point, it also asked for a WiFi password, it no longer does and, apparently, can connect to my hotspot.

Recovery still does not work:

1. Pressed Power + Volume Up + Volume Down.
2. Got two teeny lines: Recovery Mode: Volume Up and Factory Mode: Volume Down.
3. No matter what I press, the screen goes dark and nothing happens (boot cycles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that repeating the steps, i.e.,

- re-flash the phone with `BLU_L0070UU_V12_GENERIC`
- press `Power` + `Volume Up` + `Volume Down`
- get two teeny lines: `Recovery Mode: Volume Up` and `Factory Mode: Volume Down`
- press `Volume Up`

solved the problem